# How do I sort a vector by a field in a nested struct?

Tags: sorting, struct, rust

I can sort `Vec<Answer>`, but I need to sort by the field `place` in the nested struct.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Reply {
    final_text: String,
    structure: Vec<Answer>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Answer {
    place: u8,
    text: String,
}

fn main() {
    let a1: Answer = Answer {
        place: 1,
        text: String::from("test_text"),
    };
    let a2: Answer = Answer {
        place: 2,
        text: String::from("test_text"),
    };
    let a3: Answer = Answer {
        place: 3,
        text: String::from("test_text"),
    };

    let mut r: Reply = Reply {
        final_text: String::from("another_text"),
        structure: vec![a1, a2, a3],
    };

    r.sort_by_key(|a| a.structure.place);

    println!("{:?}", r);
}
```

I get an error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `sort_by_key` found for struct `Reply` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:32:7
   |
2  | struct Reply {
   | ------------ method `sort_by_key` not found for this
...
32 |     r.sort_by_key(|a| a.structure.place);
   |       ^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `Reply`
```

As far as I understand, I need to do something like:

```
impl Reply {
    fn sort_by_key(???) {
        ?????????
    }
}
```

How can I implement sorting on a nested struct?

Comment: It looks like you just put `.structure` in the wrong place: try `r.structure.sort_by_key(|answer| answer.place);`

Comment: [And applied in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e42aa9adb40b32027907e5502b87fbea).

Comment: Thank you very much Shepmaster and trentcl - it works!
As you said, I just specified sort_by_key in the wrong place

Answer (score 2):

As I was told in the comments, I was wrong about:

```
r.sort_by_key(|a| a.structure.place);
```

The correct code would be:

```
r.structure.sort_by_key(|a| a.place);
```

Thank you so much for your help!